# Achieve a parameter of the json set

Tags: javascript, json, console.log

I have code in JavaScript language and when I put console.log(event) the out put is :

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"","geometry":null,"properties":{"GRAY_INDEX":176}}],"totalFeatures":"unknown","numberReturned":1,"timeStamp":"2021-03-03T14:04:13.362Z","crs":null}
```

I want "GRAY_INDEX" Value in "properties" part . what should I do?
here is my code :

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
    var view = map.getView();
    var viewResolution = view.getResolution();
    var url = UnTiled.getSource().getFeatureInfoUrl(
        evt['coordinate'],
        viewResolution,
        'EPSG:3857', 
        {'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json'}
      );
      console.log(url);
      if (url) {
        fetch(url)
          .then(function (response) { return response.text(); })
          .then(function (html) {
            html;
            console.log(html);
          });
      }
      
     });
```

I tried :

```
console.log(html["properties"]
```

but console said undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you formatted the json, you'd be able to see more clearly how to access it:

```json
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "",
      "geometry": null,
      "properties": {
        "GRAY_INDEX": 176
      }
    }
  ],
  "totalFeatures": "unknown",
  "numberReturned": 1,
  "timeStamp": "2021-03-03T14:04:13.362Z",
  "crs": null
}
```

If the above is assigned to `html`, then to access the `GRAY_INDEX` value, you'd do:

```js
html.features[0].properties.GRAY_INDEX
```

You'd want to first parse the response as JSON by either using `response.json()` instead of `response.text()` or by adding `html = JSON.parse(html)` before trying to access it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you get the JSON representation of your JavaScript Object in parameter 'html', if this is the case you first need to parse JSON to a Object. Than you want to access properties of the features. Features is an array so per instance if you want to get properties of all elements you should do:

```js
var html = '{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"","geometry":null,"properties":{"GRAY_INDEX":176}}],"totalFeatures":"unknown","numberReturned":1,"timeStamp":"2021-03-03T14:04:13.362Z","crs":null}';
var o = JSON.parse(html);
o.features.forEach(function(each, index) { 
  console.log(`index = ${index}\n`,each.properties);
});
```